# How to extract triples in Python?

Tags: python

I am dealing with a large text file. There are many lines in the file, in which five of them are shown below.

```
/a/[/r/Antonym/,/c/af/afghanistan/,/c/af/pakistan/]
/a/[/r/UsedFor/,/c/en/book/,/c/en/learn/]
/a/[/r/Antonym/,/c/ar/???/,/c/ar/???/]
bad line
/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/island/,/c/en/land_mass/]
```

where `/a` means an assertion, `/r` means relations, `/c` means concept, and `/en` or `/af` means the language.

What I now want to do is to extract triples only for `/en` (English) language. The output I wish to obtain and stored in another file are:

```
UsedFor book learn
IsA island land_mass
```

Is there any easy way to do it using Python?

Comment: *Now* you've made it clearer. Have you made any attempts yourself yet to parse the format?

Comment: Yes, but it's trivial. I am trying now with the help of the answer below but there are still exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to parse this custom format. One possible solution could look like this:

```
s = """/a/[/r/Antonym/,/c/af/afghanistan/,/c/af/pakistan/]
/a/[/r/UsedFor/,/c/en/book/,/c/en/learn/]
/a/[/r/Antonym/,/c/ar/???/,/c/ar/???/]
bad line
/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/island/,/c/en/land_mass/]"""

for line in s.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith("/a"):
        a = line[4:-1]
        r, c1, c2 = a.split(",")
        if c1.split("/")[2] == "en" and c2.split("/")[2] == "en":
            print(" ".join((r.split("/")[2], c1.split("/")[3], c2.split("/")[3])))
```

Output:

```
UsedFor book learn
IsA island land_mass
```